# Restarting Odoo 10.0 Enterprise

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

I am working on Odoo 10 enterprise code. I have installed the code on Centos server with my licence key. So I can see that Python code is installed in the Python path.

I would like to make some changes on the code like changing the logo in the home page and customizing the purchase order module, etc.

Could anyone please let me know how can I restart the Odoo server after I make changes.

I cant find `odoo-bin` after it is installed in my server. And I have a mapping to `/etc/odoo/odoo.conf`.

When I restart using `service odoo restart` changes are not coming.

And I cant restart modules like 'service odoo restart -u all'

Anyone help is appreciated here.

Comment: What kind of changes have you tried here, did you tried adding a new module to the modules list? Or Is it just a few python code changes?

Answer (score 2):

I got this answer from [Technoalerts](https://www.technoalerts.com/) which I'll share with you. After modification in your code, you have to restart your Odoo service. Then you have to

1. Stop your server.
2. Restart server again

Your changes will reflect in your Odoo system.

[image]

Still, if you cannot see the changes you have made then upgrade your apps.

For that just go to Apps-> Update App list. Then open the desired app in which you have made the changes and from there upgrade the app.

[image]

I hope you find this article helpful and resolved your problem too. If not then do let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using **odoo service start** use **service odoo-server restart**.

Or You can use command in terminal from odoo folder directory

**./odoo-bin -u your-module-name**

Answer (score 1):

There are two things

1. when python code is changed
2. when xml code is changed

I the first case, you need to restart the service, which can be done using the following  command

- for linux

`sudo systemctl stop odoo-server` to stop service and

`sudo systemctl start odoo-server` to start odoo service.

- for windows

`net stop odoo-server-10.0` to stop service and

`net start odoo-server-10.0` to start service

In second case, you need to update your module by opening your module in app list(in Odoo) and clicking `Upgrade` button.

And `odoo-bin` can be found in `server` directory inside odoo